# For what $n$ and $m$ is $RS(n, m)$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, universal-algebra

Let's define the relatively symmetric group $RS(n, m)$, as the relatively free group in ${\rm Var}(S_n)$ on $m$ generators. Is it known, for what $n$ and $m$ is $RS(n, m)$ finite?

For $m = 1$ it always does, as $RS(n, m)$ is a cyclic group of finite exponent. For $n < 4$ it is also true, because any finitely generated group of exponents $1$, $2$ or $6$ is finite. This however, already does not work with $n = 4$, as the exponent of $S_4$ is $12$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the finitely generated groups in $\mathrm{Var}(A_n)$, $n\geq 5$, are all finite: they are isomorphic to a finite product of copies of $A_k$'s with $5\leq k\leq n$ and a solvable group that is in $\mathrm{Var}((HS-1)(A_n))$, the homomorphic images of the proper subfactors of $A_n$ (groups of the form $H/N$ with $H\leq A_n$ and $N\triangleleft H$). As there are only finitely many possible subfactors, the finitely generated groups will be embeddable in a finite product of finite groups. I would expect the same argument to work for $S_n$.

Comment: I was going to post what Keith said: since they are elements of $HSP(S_n)$, it is easy to verify that a finitely generated subgroup of a power of $S_n$ is finite, and hence that a finitely generated quotient of a subgroup of a power of $S_n$ is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any variety generated by a finite algebraic structure is locally finite.
This means that the finitely generated relatively free algebras in any finitely generated variety are finite. 
Thus, $RS(m,n)$ is finite for any finite $m$ and $n$.